# Cancel the notification after vote or comment urself's post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my Vote model

```
  def send_vote_notification
    vote_type = self.vote ? 'love' : 'hate'
    article = ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to self.voteable.content[0..30], url_helpers.micropost_path(self.voteable), target: '_blank'
    Notification::Vote.create user_id: self.voteable.user_id, body: "a user #{vote_type} #{article}"
  end
```

This is my Comment model

```
  def send_comment_notification

    article = ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to self.micropost.content[0..30], url_helpers.micropost_path(self.micropost), target: '_blank'

    Notification::Comment.create user_id: self.micropost.user_id, body: "a user add a comment for your article: #{article}"
  end
```

The problem now is i want to stop send user notifications if he add or vote his own post. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In model

check if micropost not belongs to `current_user`

```
 def send_comment_notification
      article = ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to self.micropost.content[0..30], url_helpers.micropost_path(self.micropost), target: '_blank'
      Notification::Comment.create user_id: self.micropost.user_id, body: "a user add a comment for your article: #{article}" if self.micropost.user_id != self.id
 end
```